# My melody looks awful

Tags: notation, melody

I was just improvising on my piano when I came across a melody that I liked. I sat down and tried to write it down. It resulted in excessive triplets and time signatures changing every bar. So could it be possibly written down better?
[Here is the midi file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-VwS-ThV5jSenAtdVJ0NmFQVnc)

[image]

Comment: Well is that the meter you were playing in?  I notice that every group of 5/4 and 3/4 adds up to 8 beats, which makes me think it is possible this is really just in 4/4.  I couldn't open that audio file so I was unable to listen to it, but are you sure this is the meter pattern you are using?  If it is, then this is how it looks.  Are you really counting "1,2,3,4,5 , 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3" as you play?

Comment: I agree with Rockwell and I would add that it should be 12/8 time to make the triplets not triplets. If you have a triplet feel for almost a whole piece, it's usually better to write it in compound time, unless you're Ravel writing *Bolero*.

Comment: The first time I wrote down a composition I unconsciously tweaked note durations to make them more "even", and ended up with a similar result.  Are the timings in your midi file _exactly_ the same as what you would play?

Comment: You may consider using 4 sharps in the key signature instead of just 3. The melody is pretty clearly in E major, so unless you're intentionally writing it in E Mixolydian, 4 sharps would probably be a better key signature.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't technically EXACTLY the rhythm of yours, but this is what I hear when I listen to the midi file, and it seems to be what you're going for:[image]

Obviously you could make changes like making it dotted quarters + eighth note + two quarter notes, or making it in 6/4 or 4/4+2/4 or something funky, but this is how I would write the melody.
[Here is a midi file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw3ir1ukDLcMZzc3TG1MZF91MFU)

Comment: I would double the note durations because I hear the last three notes of the phrase as downbeats (the `E F♯ G♯`). This would put the rhythms at dotted quarter + eighth note + two quarter notes, as you suggested. I independently came up with that exact same rhythm when whistling the tune to myself.